# SQL Select distinct users that listen to a certain artist

Tags: sql, distinct

I'm having some problems with my SQL query. Im trying to select every user that listens to a certain artist, in this case Kings of Leon.

This is my query, and it works:

```
SELECT *
FROM artists, tracks, playcount
WHERE playcount.songid = tracks.id
AND tracks.artistname = artists.name
AND artists.name = "Kings of Leon";
```

The problem with the query above is that I get several records of the same users. Now I want to select every unique username, and this query does not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT playcount.user
FROM artists, tracks, playcount
WHERE playcount.songid = tracks.id
AND tracks.artistname = artists.name
AND artists.name = "Kings of Leon" LIMIT 0,10;
```

Hope someone could help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error? Or what "not work" means?

Comment: Unless this is just a throwaway query (in other words, code you don't need to maintain in the future), you should consider writing ``JOIN`` clauses instead of putting multiple table names in the ``FROM``.

Comment: I'm working in a 4GIG database (using SQLLite studio), the first query nicely returns all the expected row. As soon as I use DISTINCT it takes ages to execute the query, but I don't get an error. It just never completes. Even if I use LIMIT 0,10.